# Azure Pipelines, Hosted Ubuntu Agent and Azure CLI Task with PowerShell Core: Use Az module and authenticate properly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, azure-pipelines, azure-cli, powershell-core

I have a couple of PowerShell scripts that use the PowerShell Az module ([Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-4.2.0)). As a result of certain requirements it is now necessary to run these scripts on a hosted Ubuntu agent (18.04).

So I selected the Azure CLI task with PowerShell Core as Script type

[image]

The first issue I encounter is that the agent does not  know the Az cmdlets. The second issue is that even when the Az cmdlets are available there is no authenticated context to work with them.

How can I resolve these two issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First it is necessary to install the Az module on the hosted Ubuntu agent. This can be done with a Azure CLI task with script type PowerShell Core by executing

`Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Force`

To then be able to authenticate it is necessary to enable on the task

[image]

and then in the PowerShell script to authenticate via

```
$tenantIdEnv = $env:tenantId
$spnIdEnv = $env:servicePrincipalId
$spnKeyEnvSecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString $env:servicePrincipalKey -AsPlainText -Force
$credentialsServicePrincipal = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($spnIdEnv, $spnKeyEnvSecureString)
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $tenantIdEnv -Credential $credentialsServicePrincipal
```